# Using SQL Server to find a list of holidays that fall between two dates

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get a list of holidays that overlap a timespan from an appointment table.  For example, Christmas Break is Wednesday the 24th through Friday the 26th., and I need to return this holiday when the following appointment overlaps it.

Holidays Table:

```
HolidayID     Name              StartDate     EndDate  
---------     ---------------   ----------    ----------  
1             Christmas Break   12/24/2014    12/26/2014
```

Appointments Table:

```
AppointmentID     PatientID     AppointmentDateTime   AppointmentDuration  
-------------     ---------     -------------------   -------------------  
1                 345           12/23/2014T23:00:00     02:00:00.0000000
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e01d3/3

#### Working SQL:

```
SELECT AppointmentID
    , PatientID
    , Name AS HolidayName
FROM Appointment A JOIN Holiday H
ON A.AppointmentDateTime BETWEEN H.StartDate AND H.EndDate
```

#### Create TABLES and INSERT Data

```
CREATE TABLE Holiday
(
    HolidayID INT NOT NULL,
    Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    StartDate DATE NOT NULL,
    EndDate  DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Holiday VALUES
(1,'Christmas Break','12/24/2014','12/26/2014'),
(2,'New Year Eve','12/31/2014','12/31/2014');

CREATE TABLE Appointment
(
    AppointmentID INT NOT NULL,
    PatientID INT NOT NULL,
    AppointmentDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    AppointmentDuration  TIME NULL
);

INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES
(1, 345, '12/25/2014 23:00:00','02:00:00.0000000');
```

#### Run SQL

```
SELECT AppointmentID
    , PatientID
    , Name AS HolidayName
FROM Appointment A JOIN Holiday H
ON A.AppointmentDateTime BETWEEN H.StartDate AND H.EndDate
```

#### Results

```
APPOINTMENTID   PATIENTID   HOLIDAYNAME
1               345         Christmas Break
```

Comment: My problem revolves around the timespan from AppointmentdateTime to AppointmentDateTime + Appointment Duration.  If any time within that period overlaps a holiday, then I need to know.

Answer (score 1):

a version without table
local holidays from my country(Turkey)
which includes some religion-related holidays used with Hijri calendar;

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_IsItHoliday](@Tarih datetime) 
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN 

RETURN case 
when CONVERT(nchar,@Tarih,131) like ' 2/10/%' then 1 --'Ramazan Bayramı 1.Günü'
when CONVERT(nchar,@Tarih,131) like ' 3/10/%' then 1 --'Ramazan Bayramı 2.Günü'
when CONVERT(nchar,@Tarih,131) like ' 4/10/%' then 1 --'Ramazan Bayramı 3.Günü'
when CONVERT(nchar,@Tarih,131) like '10/12/%' then 1 --'Kurban Bayramı 1.Günü'
when CONVERT(nchar,@Tarih,131) like '11/12/%' then 1 --'Kurban Bayramı 2.Günü'
when CONVERT(nchar,@Tarih,131) like '12/12/%' then 1 --'Kurban Bayramı 3.Günü'
when CONVERT(nchar,@Tarih,131) like '13/12/%' then 1 --'Kurban Bayramı 4.Günü'
when CONVERT(varchar,@Tarih, 121) like '____-01-01%' then 1 --'Yılbaşı'
when CONVERT(varchar,@Tarih, 121) like '____-04-23%' then 1 --'Ulusal Egemenlik ve Çocuk Bayramı'
when CONVERT(varchar,@Tarih, 121) like '____-05-19%' then 1 --'Atatürk’ü Anma Gençlik ve Spor Bayramı'
when CONVERT(varchar,@Tarih, 121) like '____-07-15%' then 1 --'Demokrasi Bayramı'
when CONVERT(varchar,@Tarih, 121) like '____-08-30%' then 1 --'Zafer Bayramı'
when CONVERT(varchar,@Tarih, 121) like '____-10-29%' then 1 --'Cumhuriyet Bayramı'
else 0 end

END


declare @Date Datetime, @Year int
set @Date = '2018-01-01'
set @Year = Year(@Date)

while year(@Date)=@Year
begin
    if [dbo].[fn_IsItHoliday](@Date)
    ---
        --here you can list your holidays however you like
    ---
    set @Date=dateadd(day,1,@Date)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Two time periods overlap when one starts before the second ends and the first ends after the second starts.  You can use this logic in a query:

```
select a.*, h.Name
from Appointments a join
     Holidays h
     on h.EndDate >= cast(a.AppointmentDate as date) and
        h.StartDate <= cast(a.AppointmentDate + a.AppointmentDuration as date);
```

Comment: `Appointments` tables does not have a `EndDate` or `StartDate` column. Did you mean to say `h.EndDate` and `h.StartDate` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe...

```
SELECT 
  h.* 
FROM 
  Holidays h 
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
      *, 
      DATEADD(
        hour, a.AppointmentDuration, a.AppointmentDateTime
      ) [AppointmentEnd] 
    FROM 
      Appointments a
  ) aa ON aa.AppointmentDateTime BETWEEN h.StartDate 
  AND h.EndDate 
  OR aa.AppointmentEnd BETWEEN h.StartDate 
  AND h.EndDate 
WHERE 
  aa.AppointmentId = 1
```